# Collinear predictors in a GLM

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

**Context:**  I'm familiar with the problems of collinear regressors-- i.e. the general model fit is interpretable but a direct comparison of the predictors is not.

I have 2 regressors that are highly correlated and would like to know the relative contribution of each regressor on my outcome variable.

**Question:** What is the best approach here?

**Attempt:** I have tried to do a partial correlation of each regressor with the outcome (with the other regressor partialed out).  My understanding is that this is more aggressive than running a GLM with both regressors, where the variance may get assigned a bit haphazardly to one or the other.

It seems like the ideal scenario would be to characterize the variance common to both regressors and then have a GLM with 3 regressors-- the common component, the unique component of the first regressor, and the unique component of the second regressor.  Essentially, I would need to solve the equations

```
r1 = unique_1 + common 
r2 = unique_2 + common
```

and then have

`DV = unique_1 + unique_2 + common`.

However, I have not seen this kind of a solution in any searches I have done for collinear regressor workarounds. Conceptually, this seems related to an Independent Component Analysis.

Can someone please advise on an approach that would be in line with what I'm after?